# Reducing Queries while looking for associated records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have this code, which is performing an awful lot of SQL Queries, especially with the last method ('most related'). My following setup is this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery!
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items


  def purchased_categories
    ids = []
    self.items.each do |item|
      ids << item.categories.pluck(:id)
    end
    ids.flatten.uniq
  end

  def recommended_items
    Item.includes(:categories).where("categories.id IN (?)",       self.purchased_categories).references(:categories).uniq - self.items
  end

  def most_related
    cs = self.purchased_categories
    self.recommended_items.sort { |a, b| (a.categories.pluck(:id) & cs).length <=> (b.categories.pluck(:id) & cs).length }
  end

end
```

My Item Model looks the following:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

I have a ton of queries in the most_related method, and I was wondering, If I can reduce those somehow?

Edit:

The Main Issue i'm seeing is in most_related - Its performing a Ton of queries, see below:

```
Item Load (4.1ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" INNER JOIN "items_users" ON "items"."id" = "items_users"."item_id" WHERE "items_users"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 815249]]
   (0.9ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1253]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1253]]
  SQL (2.9ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "items"."id" AS t0_r0, "items"."name" AS t0_r1, "items"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "items"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "categories"."id" AS t1_r0, "categories"."name" AS t1_r1, "categories"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "categories"."updated_at" AS t1_r3 FROM "items" LEFT OUTER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories_items"."item_id" = "items"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE (categories.id IN (134,152))
   (0.8ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1684]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1596]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1596]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1684]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1622]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1685]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.8ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1683]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1378]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1594]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1678]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1428]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1427]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1623]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1676]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1456]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1532]]
   (1.1ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1546]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1641]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1681]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1677]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.8ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1288]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1533]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1686]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1643]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1679]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1682]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.8ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1687]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1675]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1376]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1549]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1680]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1750]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1643]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1623]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1623]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1596]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1533]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1623]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1532]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1623]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1378]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1623]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1622]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_items" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_items"."category_id" WHERE "categories_items"."item_id" = $1  [["item_id", 1623]]
```

Comment: Can you paste some samples of the kind of repeated queries you're seeing in the rails console?

Comment: Added the most troublesome queries. I'm more worried about the most_related than the purchased_categories.

Comment: But most_related calls purchased_categories

Comment: It looks like `Item` is really a Join model, and may be better suited to use [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many`, and refactoring that way may make some of these queries easier. Did you intentionally not use `has_many :through`?

Comment: No, there is no reason to not use has_many :through.

Comment: The reason, why I'm not using has_many :through is, that the Item can belong to many categories. I'm not sure if this would work with that.

Comment: And notice that so many of the queries are `SELECT "categories"."id"`... that is coming from `purchased_categories` (see my updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain without seeing the exact SQL queries that your app is making, but I suspect it's suffering from the **N + 1 queries problem** in this section of code:

```
self.items.each do |item|
  ids << item.categories.pluck(:id)
end
```

That will perform a separate query for each Item to fetch its associated Categories (which is why you see so many `SELECT "categories"."id" ...` queries). But it would be more efficient to select all the Items their Categories in just two queries.

There may be other instances of this within your code above, but in general the solution to the N + 1 queries problem is to use `includes(...)` when fetching your "parent" model from the DB. Read more in the Rails Guide section on [Eager Loading Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).

**Edit**: it may be more efficient to use `has_many :through` instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many` for these model relationships, and that may help solve your problem by making the queries easier too. If you switched to `has_many :through` you would end up having something like this (with a much simpler `purchased_categories` method):

```
class User
  has_many :items
  has_many :categories, :through => :items

  def purchased_categories
    category_ids
  end
end

class Item
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Comment: The issue here is, that an Item has multiple categories. So I seem to have this issue with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to divide the sentence

```
Item.includes(:categories).where("categories.id IN (?)", self.purchased_categories).references(:categories).uniq
```

into two, one for all the ids of the Items, and the other for all the categories through the table between Item and Category, like

```
1. Item.includes(:categories).where("categories.id IN (?)", self.purchased_categories)
2. Category.includes(:items).where("items.id IN (?)", <THE ids of Items>)
```